# Copy all data from local to server and server to local

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, database-replication, mirroring

I have a win form app which is running at local using SQL Server database. The second database is at server and working. Because of internet connection problem I don't save data to server all time. My aim is that how can I copy (mirroring) data in local database to server database and copy data from server to local when added or changed data. There are foreign key problems etc.

My last goal is reach, add, or edits data from remotely on mobile or website. I tried signalR Socket it is good when local machine has connection. When connection lost I can't reach local database with signalR.

Comment: That is too broad a question for SO, there are many strategies you might employ. Your job is to research them and then come back with questions when you get stuck.

Comment: Sql server can replicate itself, there shouldn't be any need to reinvent that wheel

Comment: is there a way, services in mssql?

Comment: [Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thank you  i use and try  it. But which versinons of sql contain replication and is it free or must buy it?